# Why is there a delay before the iPad reacts to click events in my html5 game?

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-canvas, dom-events

I have an html5 game rendered on a canvas.  I've added "click" handlers on the canvas.  Here's its html:

```
<canvas id="game" width="640" height="480" onclick="void(0)"></canvas>
```

The problem is, every time I click on the canvas, there seems to be a delay of .5-1 seconds before it reacts which is really noticeable.  When I test my game out on my desktop, there is no delay at all so it has something to do with iPad/iOS.  This is not a performance issue because my game reacts to swipe events immediately.

As I have very little experience developing on this hardware, I don't really know how to debug this or even give more useful information than I am.  I'm just hoping someone out there may know something I don't.  As a hypothetical: "iOS click events have a default 500ms delay on them.  You can change this default by doing `x`".

Comment: I actually do believe there's something on iOS having to do with the double-click-zoom feature. That it will wait to make sure there is *not* a double-click before sending the click event. I also think there's a way to disable it but I don't remember exactly right now

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12417114/31158)

Comment: @Jordão that was the answer, thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eliminate 300ms delay on click events in mobile Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238587/eliminate-300ms-delay-on-click-events-in-mobile-safari)